# Link to view all possible badges on the site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems that with a user interface update, we no longer have a link to view all possible badges available on the site. The only way to view the possible badges seems to now be to click on a badge I have earned, then click on the badges link to the right of the page. It seems that this link should be more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Help Center and search for "badges", you'll find the "[What are badges?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges)" page, which links to the [complete list of badges](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Hope that helps!